# How do I bake perpetual textures for export?

Tags: export, texture-baking

"
This question already has answers here:
How do I bake a texture using Cycles bake (2 answers)

Your post has been associated with a similar question. If this question doesn’t resolve your question, ask a new one.

Closed 17 hours ago.

(Private feedback for you)
"

Yes, I searched and saw the link you suggested for an answer to this question however if I felt it answered it for me, I would NOT have asked again!

## CLOSED!!!  AWESOME!!!  THIS FORUM SUCKS!  Asked 2 questions so far and BOTH CLOSED!  NICE!!!

I really love the power of creating perpetual textures however I cannot export them for use outside of blender.

I have tried exporting both .obj and .fbx and both import with a plain solid color and none of the calculated texture.

It seems I can only get proper exports with texture from using image based textures.

This is the blender version:
[image]

This is the imported object:
[image]

I tried using the bake option for cycles but I must not be doing something properly.  It does this with any perpetual texture. Archipak uses perpetual textures to calculate the roof tiles and those too are not exporting properly as they too are solid and not random.

How can I properly export my creations and keep my created textures?

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you perhaps mean **procedural** textures, rather than "perpetual"?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Yes, Procedural, thank you.

I saw the other post... was not much help as I did not really understand what they were doing.  Tried to watch a YouTube on this and still cannot figure it out.